# What are the meta tags I must use in html?

Tags: html, tags, meta

What are the meta tags I should/must use in my html file and why is it so important. I saw the souce code of many sites having a bunch of meta tags and I want to know why they are used and which ones I must use myself .

Comment: You don't have to add meta tags for the sake of doing it. It's like asking if you need to print Xmas cards—how can we know?

Comment: I am asking what's  its use, and what tags I should use for better results and good coding practices.